# Trigonometric functions (complex)

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I have to find  $sen^3{5a}$  and  $cos^2{5a}$  considering that  $sen{a}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$ and $a$ belong to the  first positive quadrant.

I tried to apply De Moivre formula to find $sen^3{z}$ and $cos^2{z}$ (I guess that somehow i can relate with $a$) but i don't know how to relate it with $sen{a}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin a=\frac12=\sin\frac\pi6\implies a=n\pi+(-1)^n\frac\pi6$$ where $n$ is any integer

As "a belong to the first positive quadrant," $\displaystyle a=\frac\pi6$ (setting $n=0$)